# Joomla SEO Friendly URL Problem

Tags: php, search, joomla, joomla1.5

In my current Joomla Project, I set the SEO friendly in URL in global configuration in Joomla 1.5. Everything worked fine except the search. When I search something, the url shows as old one (not like seo friendly url) and because of that, I had a banner image in search result page, and it's not showing now. Does anyone know how to fix the seo friendly url in Joomla Search. Please it kinda urgent.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you need to make a menu item that links to the Joomla search page. Otherwise there is no itemid to associate the search results to. If you don't already have a hidden menu, simply create a new menu and don't put it in a module, then add a link to the default search page. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Brent, the problem is, the search field is showing in every page. I can't remove and show it only in a one search page. So when I type something and press search, the search result is correct except the banner is not showing. I need only to show the banner on that page